# how to display different titles on different pages with same API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four courses on my website I have a page names as courses and there are four button with descriptions which lead to 4 different courses. The data of all courses is coming through API.

The issue is I want to display the different titles for all four pages.

Below the title API fetches its data but on top I want to display different titles for all four pages and this is the point where I am struck.

Because the main page for all four pages is same so any changes to that page bring change to all 4 pages I cannot modify all pages differently. Below is the code of my API I don't know how to modify it.

```
 (function() {

var jQuery;


if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '3.1.1') {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src", 
"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js");
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
        script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { 
            if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                scriptLoadHandler();
            }
        }
    } else script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;

    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || 
document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
}

function scriptLoadHandler() {
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    main(); 
}

function main() { 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($jq) {
    
        //$jq.support.cors = true;
        //var caller = window.location.hostname.toString(); // executing site
        /* 
        var css_link = $jq("<link>", { 
                rel: "stylesheet", 
                type: "text/css", 
                href: "//admin.rtodata.com.au/api/widget/widget.css?v=1" 
            });
            css_link.appendTo('head');
         */  
           
            
// Course list
        
        if ($jq('.rtodata-course-list').length ) {
            $jq('.rtodata-course-list').html('Retrieving the list ...');
            $jq('.rtodata-course-list').each(function(i){
                var formContainer = $jq(this);   
//console.log(formContainer.data());console.log(formContainer.data('api-key'));         
                data = {
                    "api_user": formContainer.data('api-user'),
                    "api_key": formContainer.data('api-key'),
                    "subdomain": formContainer.data('subdomain'),
                    "type": formContainer.data('type'),
                    "category": formContainer.data('category'),
                    "page": formContainer.data('page')};
                    
                var pairs = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
                for (var i in pairs) {
                    parms = pairs[i].toString().split('=');
                    data[parms[0]] = parms[1];
                }   
                $jq.ajax({
                    url: "https://" + formContainer.data('subdomain') + 
 ".rtodata.com.au/api/widget/list.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (result.success == 1) formContainer.html(result.data);
                        else formContainer.html(result.data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }   
        
 // Course links
        
        if ($jq('.rtodata-course-links').length ) {
            $jq('.rtodata-course-links').html('Retrieving the links ...');
            $jq('.rtodata-course-links').each(function(i){
                var formContainer = $jq(this);   
 //console.log(formContainer.data());console.log(formContainer.data('api-key'));            
                data = {
                    "api_user": formContainer.data('api-user'),
                    "api_key": formContainer.data('api-key'),
                    "subdomain": formContainer.data('subdomain'),
                    "icon-class": formContainer.data('icon-class'),
                    "type": formContainer.data('type'),
                    "category": formContainer.data('category'),
                    "limit": formContainer.data('limit'),
                    "all": formContainer.data('all'),
                    "page": formContainer.data('page')};
                $jq.ajax({
                    url: "https://" + formContainer.data('subdomain') + 
  ".rtodata.com.au/api/widget/list.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (result.success == 1) formContainer.html(result.data);
                        else formContainer.html(result.data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }   
        
 // Course categories
        
        if ($jq('.rtodata-course-categories').length ) {
            $jq('.rtodata-course-categories').html('Retrieving the categories ...');
            $jq('.rtodata-course-categories').each(function(i){
                var formContainer = $jq(this);   
 //console.log(formContainer.data());console.log(formContainer.data('api-key'));            
                data = {
                    "api_user": formContainer.data('api-user'),
                    "api_key": formContainer.data('api-key'),
                    "subdomain": formContainer.data('subdomain'),
                    "icon-class": formContainer.data('icon-class'),
                    "type": formContainer.data('type'),
                    "page": formContainer.data('page')};
                $jq.ajax({
                    url: "https://" + formContainer.data('subdomain') + 
 ".rtodata.com.au/api/widget/list.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (result.success == 1) formContainer.html(result.data);
                        else formContainer.html(result.data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }   
        
 // Course Detail
        
        if ($jq('.rtodata-course-detail').length ) {
            $jq('.rtodata-course-detail').html('Retrieving the detail ...');
            $jq('.rtodata-course-detail').each(function(i){
                var formContainer = $jq(this);
                
                data = {
                    "api_user": formContainer.data('api-user'),
                    "api_key": formContainer.data('api-key'),
                    "subdomain": formContainer.data('subdomain'),
                    "page": formContainer.data('page'),
                    "code": window.location.search.split('=')[1]
                };
                    
                var pairs = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
                for (var i in pairs) {
                    parms = pairs[i].toString().split('=');
                    data[parms[0]] = parms[1];
                }   
                    
                $jq.ajax({
                    url: "https://" + formContainer.data('subdomain') + 
 ".rtodata.com.au/api/widget/detail.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (result.success == 1) formContainer.html(result.data);
                        else formContainer.html(result.data);
                    }
                });
            });
        } 
        
 // Course Calendar
        
        if ($jq('.rtodata-course-calendar').length ) {
            $jq('.rtodata-course-calendar').html('Retrieving the calendar ...');
            $jq('.rtodata-course-calendar').each(function(i){
                var formContainer = $jq(this);
                
                data = {
                    "api_user": formContainer.data('api-user'),
                    "api_key": formContainer.data('api-key'),
                    "subdomain": formContainer.data('subdomain'),
                    "page": formContainer.data('page'),
                    "type": formContainer.data('type')
                };  
                    
                $jq.ajax({
                    url: "https://" + formContainer.data('subdomain') + 
 ".rtodata.com.au/api/widget/calendar.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (result.success == 1) formContainer.html(result.data);
                        else formContainer.html(result.data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }           
        
 // Certificate Check
        
        if ($jq('.rtodata-certificate-check').length ) {
            $jq('.rtodata-certificate-check').html('Working ...');
            $jq('.rtodata-certificate-check').each(function(i){
                var formContainer = $jq(this);
                
                data = {
                    "api_user": formContainer.data('api-user'),
                    "api_key": formContainer.data('api-key'),
                    "subdomain": formContainer.data('subdomain'),
                };
                
                var pairs = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
                for (var i in pairs) {
                    parms = pairs[i].toString().split('=');
                    data[parms[0]] = parms[1];
                }   
                    
                $jq.ajax({
                    url: "https://" + formContainer.data('subdomain') + 
 ".rtodata.com.au/api/widget/check.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (result.success == 1) formContainer.html(result.data);
                        else formContainer.html(result.data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }           
        
 // Registration
        
        if ($jq('.rtodata-course-registration').length ) {
            $jq('.rtodata-course-registration').html('Loading the form ...');
            $jq('.rtodata-course-registration').each(function(i){
                
                var formContainer = $jq(this);
                data = {
                    "api_user": formContainer.data('api-user'),
                    "api_key": formContainer.data('api-key'),
                    "subdomain": formContainer.data('subdomain'),
                    "page": formContainer.data('page'),
                    "employer": formContainer.data('employer'),
                    "code": window.location.search.split('=')[1]};
                var pairs = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
                for (var i in pairs) {
                    parms = pairs[i].toString().split('=');
                    data[parms[0]] = parms[1];
                }   
                $jq.ajax({
                    url: "https://" + formContainer.data('subdomain') + 
 ".rtodata.com.au/api/widget/register.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (result.success == 1) formContainer.html(result.data);
                        else formContainer.html('Error: ' + result.data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
                    
        $jq("body").on('change', ".rtodata-course-registration .course-section select", 
 function() {
            var selected = $jq("option:selected", this);
            //window.location = selected.data('url');
            window.location.search = selected.data('url');
        });
        
        $jq("body").on('change', ".rtodata-course-registration .toggle-next", function() {
            if ($jq("option:selected", this).val() == 1 || $jq("option:selected", this).val() 
 == 'Y') $jq(this).closest('tbody').next().show();
            else $jq(this).closest('tbody').next().hide();
        });
        
        $jq("body").on('change', ".rtodata-toggle", function() {
            $jq('.'+ $jq(this).attr('name')).slideToggle();
            return false;
        });
        
        $jq("body").on('change', ".rtodata-course-registration .toggle-group", function() {
            if ($jq("option:selected", this).val()) {
                $jq(this).css({
                        "outline-style": "inherit",
                        "outline-width": "inherit",
                        "outline-color": "inherit"
                }).removeClass('rtodata-highlighted'); 
            }
            else {
                $jq(this).css({
                        "outline-style": "solid",
                        "outline-width": "1px",
                        "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                }).addClass('rtodata-highlighted');
            }
            if ($jq("option:selected", this).val() == 1 || $jq("option:selected", this).val() 
 == 'Y') {
                $jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name')).show();
                
            }   
            else $jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name')).hide();
        });
        
        $jq("body").on('change', ".rtodata-course-registration select[name='usi_exemption']", 
 function() {
            if ($jq(this).data('required')) {
                if ($jq("option:selected", this).val() == '') {
                     
 $jq(this).closest('tbody').find("input[name='usi_number']").prop('required', true);
                    $jq(this).closest('tbody').find("input[name='usi_number']").css({
                      "outline-style": "solid",
                      "outline-width": "1px",
                      "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                    }).addClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                }   
                else {
                     
 $jq(this).closest('tbody').find("input[name='usi_number']").prop('required', false);
                    $jq(this).closest('tbody').find("input[name='usi_number']").css({
                      "outline-style": "inherit",
                      "outline-width": "inherit",
                      "outline-color": "inherit"
                    }).removeClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                }   
            }
        });
        
        $jq("body").on('change', ".rtodata-course-registration select[name='state']", 
 function() {
            if ($jq("option:selected", this).val() == '99') 
 $jq(this).closest('tbody').find("input[name='postcode']").val('OSPC');
            else $jq(this).closest('tbody').find("input[name='postcode']").val('');
        }); 
        
         $jq("body").on('change', ".rtodata-course-registration select[name='postal_state']", 
 function() {
                if ($jq("option:selected", this).val() == '99') 
 $jq(this).closest('tbody').find("input[name='postal_postcode']").val('OSPC');
            else $jq(this).closest('tbody').find("input[name='postal_postcode']").val('');
        }); 
        
        $jq("body").on('click', ".registration-submit", function() {
            var button = $jq(this);
            var formOK = true;
            
          var form = $jq(this).closest('form');
             /* if (!form[0].checkValidity()) {
                formOK = false;
            }*/
    
            $jq(".registration-response").html('<p>Checking ...</p>');
            
            $jq('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
                if ($jq(this).is(':checked')) $jq("." + $jq(this).attr('id')).val(1);
                else $jq("." + $jq(this).attr('id')).val(0);
            });
            
            $jq(".registration-form input[required], .registration-form select[required], 
 .registration-form textarea[required]").each(function() {
                //console.log($jq(this).attr('name'));console.log($jq(this).val());
                if ($jq(this).val() == "") {
                    $jq(this).css({
                      "outline-style": "solid",
                      "outline-width": "1px",
                      "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                    }).addClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                    formOK = false;
                } else {
                    $jq(this).css({
                      "outline-style": "inherit",
                      "outline-width": "inherit",
                      "outline-color": "inherit"
                    }).removeClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                }
            }); 
            
            $jq(".registration-form input[type=radio][required]").each(function() {
                //console.log($jq(this).attr('name'));console.log($jq(this).val());
                if ($jq("input[name='" + $jq(this).attr('name') + "']:checked" ).length == 0) 
 {
                    $jq(this).css({
                      "outline-style": "solid",
                      "outline-width": "1px",
                      "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                    }).addClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                    formOK = false;
                } else {
                    $jq(this).css({
                      "outline-style": "inherit",
                      "outline-width": "inherit",
                      "outline-color": "inherit"
                    }).removeClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                }
            }); 
            /*
            $jq(".registration-form input[type=checkbox][required]").each(function() {
                //console.log($jq(this).attr('name'));
                //console.log($jq(this).val());
                if ($jq("input[name='" + $jq(this).attr('name') + "']:checked" ).length == 0) 
 {
                    $jq(this).css({
                      "outline-style": "solid",
                      "outline-width": "1px",
                      "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                    });
                    formOK = false;
                } else {
                    $jq(this).css({
                      "outline-style": "inherit",
                      "outline-width": "inherit",
                      "outline-color": "inherit"
                    });
                }
            });
            */              
            if ($jq('.declarations-section input[type=checkbox]').length) {
                $jq('.declarations-section input[type=checkbox]').each(function() 
 {//console.log($jq(this).attr('name'));
                    if ($jq(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $jq(this).css({
                          "outline-style": "inherit",
                          "outline-width": "inherit",
                          "outline-color": "inherit"
                        }).removeClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                    }   
                    else {
                        $jq(this).css({
                          "outline-style": "solid",
                          "outline-width": "1px",
                          "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                        }).addClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                        formOK = false;
                    }   
                });
            }
            
            var usi = $jq("input[name='usi_number']");
            if (usi[0]) {
                var fred = usi[0].reportValidity();
                if (usi.val() != "") {
                    if (usi[0].checkValidity()) {
                        usi.css({
                          "outline-style": "inherit",
                          "outline-width": "inherit",
                          "outline-color": "inherit"
                        }).removeClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                    } else {
                        usi.css({
                              "outline-style": "solid",
                              "outline-width": "1px",
                              "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                            }).addClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                        formOK = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if ($jq("input[name='email']").val() != "" ) {
                if (isEmail($jq("input[name='email']").val() ) ) {
                    $jq("input[name='email']").css({
                      "outline-style": "inherit",
                      "outline-width": "inherit",
                      "outline-color": "inherit"
                    }).removeClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                } else {
                    $jq("input[name='email']").css({
                          "outline-style": "solid",
                          "outline-width": "1px",
                          "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                        }).addClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                    formOK = false;
                }
            }
            
            if ($jq('.phone-group').length) {
                var phone = 0;
                $jq('.phone-group').each(function() {
                    if ($jq(this).val()) phone += 1;
                });
                        
                if (phone > 0) {
                    $jq('.phone-group').css({
                      "outline-style": "inherit",
                      "outline-width": "inherit",
                      "outline-color": "inherit"
                    }).removeClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                }   
                else {
                    $jq('.phone-group').css({
                      "outline-style": "solid",
                      "outline-width": "1px",
                      "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                    }).addClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                    formOK = false;
                }   
            }
            
            if ($jq('.toggle-group').length) {
                $jq('.toggle-group').each(function() {
                    if ($jq("option:selected", this).val() == 1 || $jq("option:selected", 
this).val() == 'Y') {
                        if ($jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + ' 
.check-boxes').length) {
                            if ($jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + 
' .check-boxes:checked').length) {
                                $jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + 
 ' .check-boxes').css({
                                    "outline-style": "inherit",
                                    "outline-width": "inherit",
                                    "outline-color": "inherit"
                                }).removeClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                            }
                            else {
                                $jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + 
 ' .check-boxes').css({
                                    "outline-style": "solid",
                                    "outline-width": "1px",
                                    "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                                }).addClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                                formOK = false;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if ($jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + ' 
 select').length) {
                            if ($jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + 
 ' select').val()) {
                                $jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + 
 ' select').css({
                                    "outline-style": "inherit",
                                    "outline-width": "inherit",
                                    "outline-color": "inherit"
                                }).removeClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                            }
                            else {
                                $jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + 
 ' select').css({
                                    "outline-style": "solid",
                                    "outline-width": "1px",
                                    "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                                }).addClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                                formOK = false;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if ($jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + ' 
 textarea').length) {
                            if ($jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + 
 ' textarea').val()) {
                                $jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + 
' textarea').css({
                                    "outline-style": "inherit",
                                    "outline-width": "inherit",
                                    "outline-color": "inherit"
                                }).removeClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                            }
                            else {
                                $jq(this).closest('tbody').find('.' + $jq(this).attr('name') + 
 ' textarea').css({
                                    "outline-style": "solid",
                                    "outline-width": "1px",
                                    "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                                }).addClass('rtodata-highlighted');
                                formOK = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            }
            
            

            /*
            if (($jq("input[name='mobile_phone']").length && 
 $jq("input[name='mobile_phone']").val() == "") && 
                ($jq("input[name='home_phone']").length && 
 $jq("input[name='home_phone']").val() == "") && 
                ($jq("input[name='work_phone']").length && 
 $jq("input[name='work_phone']").val() == "")) {
                        
                        
                $jq("input[name='mobile_phone']").css({
                      "outline-style": "solid",
                      "outline-width": "1px",
                      "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                    });
                $jq("input[name='home_phone']").css({
                      "outline-style": "solid",
                      "outline-width": "1px",
                      "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                    });
                $jq("input[name='work_phone']").css({
                      "outline-style": "solid",
                      "outline-width": "1px",
                      "outline-color": "#ffcc00"
                    });
                formOK = false;
            } else {
                $jq("input[name='mobile_phone']").css({
                      "outline-style": "inherit",
                      "outline-width": "inherit",
                      "outline-color": "inherit"
                    });
                $jq("input[name='home_phone']").css({
                      "outline-style": "inherit",
                      "outline-width": "inherit",
                      "outline-color": "inherit"
                    });
                $jq("input[name='work_phone']").css({
                      "outline-style": "inherit",
                      "outline-width": "inherit",
                      "outline-color": "inherit"
                    });
            }*/
            
            
            if(!formOK) {
                $jq (".registration-response").html('<p>Please review the highlighted 
 fields</p>');
                return false;
            }       
            else {
                $jq("body").off('click', ".registration-submit");
                button.removeClass('registration-submit');
                form.submit();
            }   
        });
        
        $jq("body").on('submit', ".registration-form", function() {
            
            var formContainer = $jq('.rtodata-course-registration');
            var response = $jq(this).closest('.rtodata-course- 
 registration').find('.registration-response');
            var success_url = $jq(this).closest('.rtodata-course-registration').data("success- 
 page");
            var failure_url = $jq(this).closest('.rtodata-course-registration').data("failure- 
page");
            var payment_url = $jq(this).closest('.rtodata-course-registration').data("payment- 
page");
            var redirect = $jq(this).closest('.rtodata-course-registration').find('.redirect- 
 form');
            $jq(".registration-response").html('Processing enrolment ...');
        
            data = {
                "api_user": formContainer.data('api-user'),
                "api_key": formContainer.data('api-key'),
                "subdomain": formContainer.data('subdomain'),
                "values": $jq(this).serialize()};
            $jq.ajax({
                url: "https://" + formContainer.data('subdomain') + 
  ".rtodata.com.au/api/widget/enrol.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(data);
                    
                    if (result.success > 0) {
                        if (result.success == 1) {
                            if (success_url) {
                                redirect.prop('action', success_url);
                                redirect.append('<input type="hidden" name="message" value="' 
 + result.data + '" />');
                                $jq.each(result.enrolment_data, function(key, value) { 
                                    redirect.append('<input type="hidden" name="' + key + '" 
   value="' + value + '" />');
                                });
                            }   
                            else response.html('0 ' +result.data);
                        }
                        else if (result.success == 2) {
                            if (payment_url) {
                                redirect.prop('action', payment_url);
                                redirect.append('<input type="hidden" name="message" value="' 
 + result.data + '" />');
                                $jq.each(result.payment_data, function(key, value) { 
                                    redirect.append('<input type="hidden" name="' + key + '" 
 value="' + value + '" />');
                                });
                            }   
                            else response.html('1 ' +result.data);
                        }
                            
                        var uploads = formContainer.find('input[type=file]');
                        var uploadsNumber = uploads.length;
                        if (uploadsNumber) {
                            var file_array = [];
                            var filesProcessed = 0;
                            uploads.each(function(i) {
                                var files = $jq(this)[0].files;
                                var filesNumber = files.length;
                                if (files.length) {
                                    $jq.each(files, function(i) {
                                        filesProcessed++;
                                        var name = this.name;
                                        var reader = new FileReader();
                                        reader.onload = function () {
                                            
                                            data = {
                                                "api_user": formContainer.data('api-user'),
                                                "api_key": formContainer.data('api-key'),
                                                "subdomain": formContainer.data('subdomain'),
                                                "enrolment_id": result.enrolment_id,
                                                "name": name,
                                                "file": reader.result
                                            };
                                            file_array.push(data);
                                            filesNumber--;
                                            if (filesNumber === 0) uploadsNumber--; // 
 finished all the files in this upload
                                            if (uploadsNumber === 0 && filesNumber === 0) { 
 //all done
                                                var deferreds = saveUploads(file_array);
                                    
                                                $jq.when.apply(null, 
 deferreds).done(function(defer) {
                                                    //console.log(defer);
                                                    redirect.submit();
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                        reader.readAsDataURL($jq(this)[0]);
                                    });
                                }
                                else {
                                    uploadsNumber--;
                                }
                                if (uploadsNumber === 0 && filesProcessed == 0) { // upload on 
  the form but no files associated
                                    redirect.submit();
                                }
                            });
                        }   
                        else {  
                            redirect.submit();
                        } 
                            
                    } 
                    else {
                        if (failure_url) {
                            redirect.prop('action', failure_url);
                            redirect.append('<input type="hidden" name="message" value="' + 
  result.data + '" />');
                        }   
                        else response.html('4 ' +result.data);
                        redirect.submit();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
        
// Payment
        
        if ($jq('.rtodata-paypal-payment').length ) {
            $jq('.rtodata-paypal-payment').html('Loading the PayPal payment ...');
            $jq('.rtodata-paypal-payment').each(function(i){
                
                var formContainer = $jq(this);
                data = {
                    "api_user": formContainer.data('api-user'),
                    "api_key": formContainer.data('api-key'),
                    "subdomain": formContainer.data('subdomain'),
                    "page": formContainer.data('page'),
                    "type": formContainer.data('type'),
                    "enrolment": window.location.search.split('=')[1]
                };
                $jq.ajax({
                    url: "https://" + formContainer.data('subdomain') + 
 ".rtodata.com.au/api/widget/payment.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (result.success == 1) formContainer.html(result.data);
                        else formContainer.html('Error: ' + result.data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ikhvjs brother I am not good in javascript now this whole code is of API I don't know how to make it minimal reproducible code maybe I miss something from the so that's why I post whole code

Comment: If you don't know how to show your problem, it is hard for people to understand your problem too.

Comment: @ikhvjs ok thanks for your comment will remember this next time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.title = "some string"` to set the title from javascript.
You can use it on the button's onclick event to change it when a user enters a different "page"